# object syntax and this in javascript

Tags: javascript

if i create an object using {} and then try to reference a property, how would i do it?

```
function Person(){
    this.name : "test";
   }

   var x = new Person();
   alert(x.name);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is off, in your case you simply do this:

```
function Person(){
    this.name = "test";
    //        ^--- =, not :
}

var x = new Person();
alert(x.name);
```

If you really want to use object literal syntax, you can, but probably best to avoid it in a constructor function (which is what you have in your code). This works, for instance, but **is not** the same as your original code:

```
var Person = {
    name: "test"
};
alert(Person.name);
```

You can even define functions that way (and people do):

```
var Person = {
    name: "test",
    speak: function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
};
Person.speak(); // alerts "test"
```

...although I'm not fan of doing that because [I prefer *named* functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) (that function is anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

The same way you access any other property.

For example:

```
alert({ name: -1 }.name);
```

---

Your code sample is invalid syntax.
The `:` character is only used in object *literals*.

To use properties in constructor (or other) functions, you should use normal assignment:

```
function Person(){
    var thing = "test";        //Assign a variable
    this.name = "test";        //Assign a property
}
alert(new Person().name);
```

Comment: in object literals, is there a way to keep the variable private?

Comment: @steve: An object literal creates a normal object.  No.

Comment: thanks, when should i use object literals or just regular syntax?

Comment: @steve: No, for that you need the module pattern or the private variables pattern where you define your accessor functions *within* your constructor function and use a var in your constructor as the underlying private variable (like Crockford does: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html). That's memory-intensive, though, you end up with separate copies of the functions *for each object*. Sometimes it's what you want; frequently it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_obj = {name:'john', age:31};
alert(my_obj.name);
```